# Delta to Y with sources?

Tags: passive-networks, network, source, equivalent-circuit

I'm wondering if this transform is possible:

[image]

I tried doing a source transformation to change this to a regular delta network with two current sources going to nodes a and b, but wasn't sure how to proceed, since we don't know what could be happening beyond nodes a and b.

**EDIT (important!):** I forgot to mention that $v_a$ and $v_b$ can be connected to *anything*, so the transformation has to be valid *whatever* is happening at and beyond $v_a$ and $v_b$. In regular delta-to-y that is possible. Is it possible here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know a transform under which voltage sources with series resistors become current sources with parallel resistors.

That transforms your left circuit into something you can already solve. Done! The end result is unambiguously impossible to transform into your right circuit.

Comment: Can you go through the calculations? I did the exact thing you mentioned, and didn't manage to bring it to the second form...

Comment: Exactly. It's impossible. That's what I'm saying.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood

Comment: Then if you recognize that, why the edit to your question. It's impossible.

Comment: Is there any similar type of circuit with sources that could be transformed? For example if I had two sources in 2 different branches in the 2nd circuit instead of just 1 source?

Comment: Yes, the original left circuit, or the transformation described in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: How do you prove that? It seems like at least *some* arrangement other than the original and source-transformed one should be possible. What if the current sources were balanced? Is it still impossible? I just feel like your answer is too vague

Comment: You can transform your resistor Y from your right circuit to a resistor delta, and the voltage source is still between ground and the bottom node of the delta. That's impossible to be equivalent to two different voltage sources. It's that simple. One fixed voltage can't be equal to two different fixed voltages.

Comment: Alright, I did not think about going backwards. Thanks